# MIT App Inventor Bluetooth connect with unpaired device

Tags: bluetooth, app-inventor

I am using **MIT App Inventor 2** to do some bluetooth connection. I am trying to connect to my Arduino Bluetooth hc05. 
I noticed that if I didn't pair my device, the app I wrote can't connect to the device.

Below is the code that I used to connect to my Bluetooth device.

[image: bluetooth connect code]

Is there any way to use the code to connect with the Bluetooth device without having to pair it first?
Or is there any way to use the code to input the pairing password using MIT App Inventor 2?

Answer (score 0):

The devices must be paired before being able to connect.

There is no Pairing method available in the App Inventor Bluetooth components. But you could write your own extension, which does the pairing.

More information about how to create an extension see [here](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/extensions.html).
However that will be more advanced and will require some Java skills...

Comment: **Update**: you now also can use my new [bluetooth extension](https://puravidaapps.com/bluetooth.php)...